# Hover on button changes variable for SQL query to show correct data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

My goal is to have several buttons and when you hover one them a div will show up with the information belonging to the button the user is hovering on.

Each button is created from my database and each button has its own value.

The value of the button its the value I'm using in my SQL query to show the correct data belonging to the button.

My problem is I'm using javascript and AJAX to get the button value off the button when the user hovers on it, which means when the information div pops up, the value I caught using AJAX is not updated until the page is refreshed.

I'm far from being an expert and I'm sure I have made it much more complexed than needed:

1) I print out the buttons from my database:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
          echo ' <input type="text" id="submitfakta" name="submitted-btn" value="'.$row['Name'].'">
```

2) I then use Javascript and AJAX to get hold of the button value on hover:

```
<script>
   $('#submitfakta').live('mouseover mouseout', function(e) {
     if (e.type == 'mouseover') {
         var idAttr = $(this).attr('value');
         //alert($(this).attr('id'));
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: 'abu.php',
             data: {idAttr : idAttr },
             success: function(data)
             {
return data;
             }
         });

     }
   });
   </script>
```

3) the information div pops up using simply css by setting display:none and when I hover on a button the div is set to display:block

4) In abu.php I tried using SESSION to get the value of the button back to my page and using for the query:

```
   $_SESSION["abu"] = $_POST["idAttr"];
```

But this is a poor solution because the session does not update right as you hover, but first after you refresh the page.

Comment: This question and the code are an inconsistent mess. In 1)  you do not create buttons but textboxes. Also the value attribute is taken unescaped from the database row. In 2) you post an ajax request on every mouseover event, this is overkill. Store the response in the input object, once retrieved, unless the data changes in the DB meanwhile. The code for the information popping up in 3) is missing. In 4) we don't see the rest of the script. Is the session initialized first? what is the point of storing the post parameter in the session object?

Answer (score 0):

first Use Class

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo ' <input type="text" class="submitfakta" name="submitted-btn" value="'.$row['Name'].'">
```

and Then

```
   $('.submitfakta').on('mouseover', function() {
     var idAttr = $(this).attr('value');
     //alert($(this).attr('id'));
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: 'abu.php',
         data: {idAttr : idAttr },
         success: function(data)
         {
            return data;
         }
     });
 });
```

Hope This Will Works